# Detect empty page in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an iOS application which uses a `WKWebView` to display a webpage I do not have under my control. This webpage is a PWA (progressive web app) which at some points uses `history.back()`. Throughout the application this is no problem, but when called on the "start" page, nothing happens.

Flow:

- Empty (= freshly initialised webview)
- `webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://pwa.example.com")!))`
- User presses button in pwa which calls `history.back()`
- Nothing happens

In regular, desktop browsers this leads back to the start/new-tab page (if launched in empty tab/window) or to the page that was loaded before.

My goal is to detect that we are at the "start" again and close the webview. I tried every method from `WKNavigationDelegate & WKUIDelegate` but with no success so far.